# Requesting Clarification Regarding A Proof Drafted By A Novice

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

fellow StackExchange users.

I am a mathematics novice with a learning disorder requesting verification of a proof that I have devised. The majority of my "mathematical writing" has consisted entirely of unconventional and otherwise useless theorizing.

The proof is devised to show that the product of variables a and b is equivalent to variable c.

This is the proof:

$(a ∙ b) = c ⇔ Sigma(1,a,b) = c$

I am attempting to prove that the product of a and b is equivalent to c if and only if the series of a sequence beginning from the 1(th) term to the (b)th with 'a' consecutively added to itself is equivalent to 'c.'

I apologize if I am using the website's format incorrectly. I am rather inexperienced with the subject and would like to know if my mediocre proof is somewhat accurate.

The only condition that I was able to devise in which this would not apply was the premise of negative quantities. Although, I am somewhat confused on how to adjust this accordingly.

Also, if possible, could any of the experienced users on this StackExchange subsidiary refer me to an objectively-detailed resource that is suited for novices?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Doing mathematics at this level seems to require that you first define what $a \times b$ is. Seriously, you should mention what your definition of $a \times b$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to prove that

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n a = an$$

is to note that adding $a$ to itself $n$ times gives $an$. If you're looking for a formal proof, then you'll want to induct on $n$. The induction principle states that if $P(1)$ true, and $P(n)$ implies that $P(n + 1)$ is true for all integers $n$, then $P(n)$ holds for all integers $n$. Here, $P(n)$ is the statement that the sum from $1$ to $n$ of $a$ is $an$. Since $P(1)$ is obvious, suppose that $P(n)$ holds for some integer $n$. Then

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} a = \sum_{i = 1}^n a + a = an + a = a(n + 1) $$

where the third step follows from the hypothesis that $P(n)$ is true. If you're concerned about these kinds of proofs, I would suggest picking any textbook on discrete mathematics or proofs (sometimes called introductions to advanced mathematics by textbook publishers).

Comment: From my perspective, this was a very thorough explanation. Thank you very much. I will attempt to research textbooks involving discrete mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

That is true if
$b$ is an integer:
adding up $b$ copies of $a$
gives the same result as
$b$ multiplied by $a$.

I am not sure why 
this is important to you,
but you are correct.

Comment: Ah, thank you. It was significant to me because it was my first attempt at attempting to comprehend basic mathematical relations.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct also for negative numbers, for example, a=-3.

Comment: Thank you as well. I was somewhat confused on how the expression would affect negative quantities.